# What can you say about the order of $a$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that $ G$ is a non-cyclic group of order $49$ and the identity e $\neq$ a $\in$ G satisfies $a^{49} = e$. What can you say about the order of $a$?

I came to the conclusion that it would mean that the order of $a$ is $49$ or a divisor of $49$. But since it's non-cyclic, I think that would mean the order of a can't be 49 because that's the order of the group $G$. But doesn't $a^{49} = e$ mean that $ord(a) = 49$?

Comment: The order of $a$ is the *smallest* $n$ such that $a^n=e$, so, no, $a^{49}=e$ doesn't imply that the order of $a$ is $49$.

Answer (score 1):

The order of an element divides the order of the group. So if $d = |a| \to d \mid 49 \to |a| = 1,7,49$. Since $a \neq e$, and $G$ is non-cyclic, it follows that $|a| = 7$.

Comment: I just want to make sure, when you write |a|, you mean the order of a right?

Comment: I'm sure that's right, MoonDog.